# I want to upload files only from particular user and allow anyone (public) to view it on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Trying deny write permission from all and allow only single user to write to an Amazon S3 bucket, but I want all users to view it. Therefore, I have set public access on the bucket.

IAM user Joe has `AmazonS3FullAccess`.

Here is the Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy98745183475249",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt15681834712546",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buketname/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::98754131531:user/Joe"
                ]
            }
        },{
            "Sid": "Stmt15681834478323",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buketname/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        },

    ]
}
```

However, it does not appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`Deny` always beats `Allow`. Therefore, the policy is actually denying *everybody* the ability to write to the bucket.

Users have **no permission by default**, so it is typically only necessary to specify `Allow` policies.

If you wish to assign permissions to a specific IAM User, **it is better to put the permissions on the IAM User themselves**, rather than in a Bucket Policy. This makes it easier to manage permissions as more are added in future.

So, you would put a policy like this onto Joe in IAM:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowWrite",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To allow everyone in the entire world to **read** the contents of the bucket (Note: Not good from a security standpoint!), use a **Bucket Policy** like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AnyoneRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```